# How come we don't have the 'variety' wallpaper changer app tag

Tags: discussion, tags

We all know the [variety wallpaper changer](http://peterlevi.com/variety/) app. Heck, we even have its [developer](https://askubuntu.com/users/77632/peter-levi) here.

How come then we don't have the [variety](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/variety) tag?

Comment: Because "variety" can mean much much more than just an app. Also, we don't create tags just for the sake of creating tags. We only create tags when we have a question that could legibly need it/use it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- [wallpaper](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/wallpaper)
- Just "variety" is too vague
- The word primarily means http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/variety

  > Variety can also describe different things that are classified under
  >   one category or type
- I didn't know the variety wallpaper changer app before you mentioned it.
- It would be missused in a *variety* of ways.
- https://askubuntu.com/search?tab=newest&q=variety
- There is a total of 17 questions for searching "variety wallpaper" https://askubuntu.com/search?q=variety+wallpaper
- Not every app should have it's own tag.
- If there is a bug with the app - it should be reported to launchpad.
- The scope of the tag is limited to two or three questions in the search for "variety wallpaper" aka - we would not tag a question about wallpaper with the app that is a possible answer.

Comment: Something I might add. Is the OP suggesting we need a tag for every application in software center?  That would be relatively absurd and utterly non-useful.

Answer (score 2):

That is one of the tags where the real name collides with some generic term, and since I love making people read unrelated examples, lets read the case [of the [pig] tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226637/213575):

> pig /pig/ noun
> noun: pig; plural noun: pigs
>
> 1. an omnivorous domesticated hoofed mammal with sparse bristly hair and a flat snout for rooting in the soil, kept for its meat.*
>    synonyms: hog, boar, sow, porker, swine, piglet
> 2. an oblong mass of iron or lead from a smelting furnace.*
> 3. platform for analyzing large data sets that consists of a high-level language for expressing data analysis programs, coupled
>    with infrastructure for evaluating these programs.
>
> Problems with the tag: **when asking about analyzing some pig epidemic
> data array the sistem suggest to use the tag**. Relevant example: [The
> pig question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22617817/pig-epidemic-java-array)
>
> Solution: **Rename to apache-pig to prevent confusion**
>
> * Thanks to Google

Now, the reason to create a tag is: **there are experts in questions about variety?** If the answer is "yes" then create a tag that is: one, easily recognizable for experts and askers, two, unique, three, isn't render for abuse or confusion, four, there are enough questions base that warrants a tag.

If you will tell me: *but look there's X tag, and nobody seems to have problem with it, why this have?* I will tell you: *thanks, that was in the list already* or *I just have added that one in the list*.

As hbdgaf points we don't need a tag for each and every application available for Linux.